# Protecting the Mating Surface between the Catalytic Converter and Header

Tags: exhaust, paint, rust, catalytic-converter, chassis-paint

In the midst of replacing my Catalytic Converter on my 03 Nissan 350z, I have taken off the Catalytic Converter to reveal a pretty rusty mating surface between the two components. My question is what is sufficient for cleaning this area up. So far I used some parts cleaner, and a wire brush to get off the lose material (as pictured below). Is it wise to also follow up with some high temperature paint (primer/topcoat)? Perhaps a small amount of Nickel/Copper Anti-seize?

[image]

Note that there is a gasket that goes between the catalytic converter and headers
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use High temp anti-seize compound, Nickel compounds are best but more expensive than copper, which will do in your case unless it is turbocharged, then use Pure Nickel compound.

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=high+temp+anti-seize&ref=nb_sb_noss_1

Comment: Thanks for the input! I have read around and some people were claiming that where you apply your anti-seize compound it could create an exhaust leak. Is there any truth to this? If not it truly seems like anti-seize is the way to go.

Comment: Never had this happen to me in decades of working on cars for a living., internet folklore. Put some on the bolt threads also.